# Is it possible, and if so how, to step through a packet going through the linux network stack?

Tags: linux, networking, debugging

I'm looking for a way to understand better every step of the Linux network stack and how to inspect how some configuration values change the behavior.  I know there are queues, and `iptables` chains, and more.  I'd like to output logs or something when a packet is put into the queue or transferred etc.

Is it possible, and if so how, to step through a packet going through the Linux network stack?

Answer (score 0):

I doubt there is one tool that illustrates the whole way of a packet. Too many too different components are involved I guess.

But for the packet filter you can send a packet (and rather not too many of them) to the `TRACE` target in the `raw` chain, see `man iptables-extensions`. That writes a message to the kernel ring buffer (`dmesg`) for each decision i.e. shows you whether a rule matched and which or whether the policy of that chain decided the packets fate.